# How to push a new page when clicking ion-item and retrieve data

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and a list of clickable ion-item with details arrow:

```
<ion-item-group>
    <button ion-item (click)="onWhenItemClick()">
      Quand
      <ion-note item-end>{{ date }}</ion-note>
    </button>
    <button ion-item (click)="onWhereItemClick()">
      Où
      <ion-note item-end>{{ location }}</ion-note>
    </button>
  </ion-item-group>
```

As there is this arrow I would expect (as a user) to see a new page sliding from right to left when clicking on of these items.

For your information, each ion-item should bring me to a page that only displays a list of radio items.

I would like to recreate the same mechanisms as a select or a modal but with a page.

So basically I want to push a new page (easy) and be able to pop/dismiss it and handle this dismissal with as function like onDismiss().

How would you do that?
Pushing the new page is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no event for passing data back on dismiss of pages and haven't seen anything or any news about they implementing this functionality, you would really need to create modal instead of simply pushing a page.

So import `modal` on your page and add it to your constructor and do the following

```
onWhereItemClick(){
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('YourPage');
  modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    // HANDLE THE DATA YOU WANT TO PASS BACK
  });
  modal.present();
};
```

Then, in `YourPage` you'll import `ViewController`, add it to constructor and then

```
dismissModal(){
  let myData = ''; // THIS IS THE CONTENT YOU WANT TO PASS BACK
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(myData);
};
```

With this you'll be able to send data back to your page and handle it.

Hope this helps.

### EDIT

A workaround would be saving the data of your dismiss in localStorage or another way to persist it and then, when the user go back to the page you get it, something like this:

> Your Page

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.storage.get('dataYouWant').then(data =>{
    if(data){
      // HANDLE DATA
    }
  });
}

ionViewWillLeave(){
  this.storage.remove('dataYouWant');
  // REMOVE THE DATA SO IF YOU COME BACK TO THIS PAGE FROM ANOTHER WAY IT DOESN'T LOAD DATA YOU DON'T WANT
};
```

> Pushed Page

```
ionViewWillUnload(){
  this.storage.set('dataYouWant', dataYouWant);
  // SAVE DATA YOU WANT TO USE
}
```

The way when the second page is going to unload it'll save data on a localStorage to be used in your first page. If there's any concurrence problems you can try using `ionViewDidEnter()` on the first page instead of `ionViewWillEnter()`

Answer (score 1):

To go to a new page you would need to use,

```
navCtrl.push(PageName)
```

To send data along with the push,

```
navCtrl.push(PageName,{Param1:"your data"})
```

To retrieve the pushed data from other page,

```
navParams.get("Param1")
```

In your case, you can pass some data while pushing your page like this,

```
onWhenItemClick(itemData){
  this.navCtrl.push(PageName,{Param1:itemData)
}
```

and retrieve your data from the other page

Comment: this works, but you also must not forget to add `import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';` and `constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams)` in the new page

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a look at this amazing tutorial https://www.joshmorony.com/passing-data-between-pages-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Ionic's navController. It behaves very much like a stack, where you push new views onto the stack, and then pop them off to go 'back'

So to navigate to a new page you would

```
navCtrl.push(myComponent)
```

Then to go back you would remove that view from the stack with

```
navCtrl.pop()
```

You can also use `navCtrl.popToRoot()` to jump all the way back to your root view controller

Please see their docs for more examples and information at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/